# How to do this join query in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

In Django, I have two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class ProductRank(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

I put the rank into a separate table because every view of a page will cause the rank to change and I was worried that all these writes would make my other (mostly read) queries slow down.

I gather a list of `Products` from a simple query:

```
cat = Category.objects.get(pk = 1)
products = Product.objects.filter(categories = cat)
```

I would now like to get all the ranks for these products. I would prefer to do it all in one go (using a SQL join) and was wondering how to express that using Django's query mechanism.

What is the right way to do this in Django?

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization.  Do you have any profiler evidence that "all these writes would make my other queries slow down"?  Or that that effect is worse than the slow-down from the additional JOINs when you need to read the rank?  Write it the simple way first and don't optimize until you've demonstrated that it's necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done in Django, but you will need to restructure your models a little bit differently:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_rank = models.OneToOneField('ProductRank')

class ProductRank(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now, when fetching Product objects, you can following the one-to-one relationship in one query using the [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method:

```
Product.objects.filter([...]).select_related()
```

This will produce one query that fetches product ranks using a join:

```
SELECT "example_product"."id", "example_product"."name", "example_product"."product_rank_id", "example_productrank"."id", "example_productrank"."rank" FROM "example_product" INNER JOIN "example_productrank" ON ("example_product"."product_rank_id" = "example_productrank"."id")
```

I had to move the relationship field between Product and ProductRank to the Product model because it looks like select_related() follows foreign keys in one direction only.

Comment: Haha. I was just reading the docs on OneToOneField today and was wondering what it's useful for! Thanks for the great info.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't checked but:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(categories__pk=1).select_related()
```

Should grab every instance.

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to the `QuerySet`'s `select_related()` method, though I'm not positive that grabs references in both directions, it is the most likely answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Django 2.1 
From documentation

This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is 'Beatles Blog':

```
 Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')
```

Doc URL
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/